# How to configure TinySine 3G module (SIM5320E) for HTTP GET request

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, gsm, http, tcpip

I recently bought a 'TinySine 3G shield (SIM5320E) 900/2100Mhz' based on Adafruit_FONA libraries to use with Arduino Mega 2560 R3.  It successfully registered with Vodafone AU. Other functionality works (SMS, GPS) but not HTTP/TCP.

[image: View from SimCom AT Command Tester]

I'm following this [TCP/UDP section of SimCom tutorial](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/tutorial-for-simcom-m2m-modules) to receive data from a REST API. But I cannot set the APN for TCP as there is no support for `AT+CSTT` command as it seems.

I can see it's on WCDMA network.

```
    AT+CREG?
    +CREG:1,1

    AT+CPSI?
    +CPSI: WCDMA,Online,505-03,0x014E,xxxxxxx,WCDMA IMT xxxx,xxx,xxxx,0,12.0,97,12,18,500
    OK
```

**Error comes here**

```
    AT+CSTT="live.vodafone.com"
    ERROR
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue
 - With the same setup/libraries OR
 - By upgrading libraries/firmware of the module OR
 - Using any other set of commands

Please provide if any of you have a sample code to access a REST API. Appreciate your help very much.

Comment: did you follow the HTTP section of that tutorial? .... it uses commands that you did not mention in your post

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I corrected the link. I followed the TCP/UDP section to be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSTT works on GPRS modules like SIM900. I found a way to get SIM5320E working to download websites. Tested with TeraTerm and used `<Ctrl M>` and `<Ctrl J>` instead of `'<CR> <LF> OR /r/n'` characters.

**Network setup**

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","<your APN>","0.0.0.0"
AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,"IP","<your APN>"
AT+CSOCKSETPN=1
```

**Start HTTP service**
You can stop and start service if it's not responding properly.

```
AT+CHTTPSSTART
AT+CHTTPACT="www.iforce2d.net",80
```

**HTTP GET request**

```
GET /test.php HTTP/1.1  <-- don't hit enter, instead hit the below 2 keys
<Ctrl M>
<Ctrl J>
Host: www.iforce2d.net  <-- don't hit enter, instead hit the below 2 keys
<Ctrl M>
<Ctrl J>
Connection: close  <-- don't hit enter, instead hit the below 4 keys. This is useful when connecting to REST APIs to download the the respective result only.
<Ctrl M>
<Ctrl J>
<Ctrl M>
<Ctrl J>
```

To end the command and to receive results:

```
<Ctrl Z>
```

You will receive a lot of data here.

**Stop HTTP service**

```
AT+CHTTPSCLSE
AT+CHTTPSSTOP
```

You will get the contents of the website. Probably it should contain the data you need (I didn't test the content. May be you will need to tweek the result a bit.)